# breaking stick, making triangle

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We break an interval $[0,1]$ in one point (we have two pieces now), then we break bigger piece again in one point. Breaking points have uniform distribution. What is probability that we can make triangle from our pieces.

I read solution in my textbook and it starts with: $P(T)=E(P(T|X))$ where T is desired event and X is coordinate of first break. Why this equation is true? It looks like integral of density, but why $P(T|X)$ is density if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the following fact: $E(\mathbb{1}_T) = P(T)$ where $\mathbb{1}_T$ equals $1$ if $T$, and $0$ otherwise. We can easily see that this is true by checking the law of total probability:

$$
E(\mathbb{1}_T) = E(\mathbb{1}_T|T)P(T) +E(\mathbb{1}_T|T^c)P(T^c) = P(T)
$$

Where $T^c$ is the complement of the event $T$.

From there, we can use the tower law to get that:
$$
P(T) = E(\mathbb{1}_T) = E(E(\mathbb{1}_T|X)) = E(P(T|X))
$$

Where I use the fact that $P(T|X) = E(\mathbb{1}_T|X)$ (which you can show as above).

Comment: How to show it as above? Above there is equality of numbers and below equality of random variables.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by equality of numbers vs equality of random variables?

Comment: Fact from first sentence is equality of numbers, left side and right sides are numbers. Fact from last sentence (one which you say I can show as abose) is equality of random variables. Can you prove last fact too?